# How do I setup $http.post in AngularJS to send data to my url?

Tags: angularjs, api, http-post

All the documentation out there for AngularJS 1.6 is extremely ambiguous. Everybody has tutorials for how to do $http.get requests, but nothing on how to properly setup $http.post requests for version 1.6.

All I'm trying to do is setup a controller that gives my mini-project the functionality to allow the user to type in his/her city into the input box on the Home page and, when they submit it, the information for their forecast will appear on the Forecast page. So, theoretically, the controller will 'POST' data into the URL to be able to retrieve information from the Open Weather API. The Routes and everything else works just fine...I only need help for this POST method stuff.

My apologies for my code looking unintelligible. I just posted what I had.

As an aside, does anybody have REALLY good resources for documentation on AngularJS 1.6?

---

```js
(function () {
 'use strict';
 
 // MODULE
 angular.module("WeatherApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'http'])
 
  // ROUTES
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
     controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })

    .when('/forecast', {
     templateUrl: 'templates/forecast.html',
     controller: 'forecastCtrl'
    });
  })

  // SERVICES
  .service('cityService', function () {
   this.city = "Chicago";
  })

  // CONTROLLERS
  .controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope, cityService) {
   $scope.city = cityService.city;
   $scope.$watch('city', function () {
    cityService.city = $scope.city;
   });
  })

  .controller("forecastCtrl", function ($scope, $http, cityService) {
   $scope.city = cityService.city;
   
   $http.post("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", {q: $scope.city, cnt: 2, appid: "8a3dfe91838e8409da30958ed6b68932"}).then(function (data) {
    console.log();
   });
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <h4>Forecast by City</h4>
  <div class="form-group"><input ng-model="city" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
  <a href="#!/forecast" class="btn btn-primary">Get Forecast</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to use `ng-click` of Get Forecast button (or button used as link) to call a method defined on `$scope` and in that method you'll need to use `$http.post`. `$http.post` looks good. You don't need multiple controllers to do this.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a full example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `$http.post`. The API returns with an error and I hope you can investigate on that.

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', []);

angular
  .module('MyApp')
  .controller('ForecastController', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope,
      $http) {

      $scope.vm = {
        city: 'Newyork',
        errorMessage: ''
      }

      $scope.getForecast = function() {
        var vm = $scope.vm;
        console.log('Getting forecast for ' + vm.city + ' city');

        /*$http.get("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1")*/
        $http.post("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", {
            q: vm.city,
            cnt: 2,
            appid: "8a3dfe91838e8409da30958ed6b68932"
          })
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log('Got forecast successfully.');
          }, function(error) {
            var message = 'There was an error getting forecast';
            console.log(message);
            console.log(error);
            vm.errorMessage = message;
          });
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .item-row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .item-row:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
</style>
<div ng-app="MyApp">

  <div ng-controller="ForecastController">
    <div class="item-row" ng-show="vm.errorMessage">
      {{vm.errorMessage}}
    </div>
    <div class="item-row">
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.city" />
    </div>
    <div class="item-row"> You entered: {{vm.city}}</div>
    <div class="item-row">
      <button ng-click="getForecast()">Get Forecast</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```